# Is this possible with HTML5?

Tags: html

I have a client who wants a none flash website very similar to the following template:

http://www.templatemonster.com/flash-templates/34056.html

I am always willing to learn, but I want to know first of all if this would be possible to create in HTML5. I realize this would only work on latest versions of IE, Firefox or Chrome.

Thanks guys!

Comment: "this would only work on latest versions of IE, Firefox or Chrome" Not really. You can't do this via CSS3 transformations only for older browser, but most features may be build up using JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating such a website with all the flashy effects and transitions can be a real pain for beginners. In this case you would have to deal with either CSS3 transitions or javascript (jquery) and do a lot of extra work, just to get that special effect.

To get you started with HTML5, have a look at [Dive into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/)

If you want a good backwards compatibility for html5 features, have a look at: http://afarkas.github.com/webshim/demos/ or http://html5boilerplate.com/

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible. Everything on that page can be done with HTML5/CSS3/Javascript. Though some of it more easily than other parts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, html5, javascript, jquery, css3 are your best friends. Check http://processingjs.org/ for a very powerful canvas lib. They've just released their 1.3.0 version.
/Richard

Answer (score 0):

I've seen entire games developed with `<canvas>` element. I think this is doable, albeit a fair amount of work. But do promise to leave the annoying guitar riffs out... :)

Comment: Yeah keep out the audio - I also believe it to be possible without too much canvas abuse.

Comment: You don't even need a canvas, as most of those effects may be done via CSS3 transformations on simple HTML-elements (like images inside figures).

Answer (score 0):

Some combination of:

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/multiple.html (click "open all")

and the shaking effect from:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/

Would be pretty similar. If you're going to be learning HTML5 from scratch, make use of JQuery - a lot of people that have been doing this a lot longer have already tackled a lot of the common requests.

Answer (score 0):

there is a flash-like tool from HTML5 called [Hype](http://www.tumultco.com/hype/) .... check this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rVeMA-hewH4&feature=related)

Comment: using UI to create animation much better than writing animation with code and you not see what really happen. so i recommend to use something like Hype. note: Hype need mac